# Recursive stack size

Tags: ruby, recursion, stack

How i can know the current method stack frame while a recursive call in ruby?

Comment: could you please post your code otherwise the answer couldn't be better as: the space you allocate per call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you would need that, but `caller.size` should do the job:

```
def recurse(n)
  puts caller.size
  recurse(n-1) unless n <= 0
end

recurse(5)  # => Outputs 1 to 6
```

This works in Ruby 1.9, but there is apparently a bug in Ruby 1.8. Just filed it [on redmine](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3011).